# Adding custom number to timepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make time picker, filled with numbers that I get from the backend. For example, the backend sent to me the time ranges when the product can light up, meaning initial value and how long can light up. Example,
backend sends to the start time 17 hours, and the maximum range 3 hours. In first picker we select 17 and in second time picker choose the ultimate value of which shall not be less than the selected start value (17) and do not exceed the maximum time range that I received from the backend.

here is html

```
<p>From</p>
<div uib-timepicker ng-model="mytimeStart" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian" readonly-input=true></div>
<p>To</p>
<div uib-timepicker ng-model="mytimeEnd" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian" readonly-input=true></div>

<pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime | date:'shortTime' }}</pre>
```

my ctrl is here (example of service)

```
  $http.get(serviceBase + 'article')
            .success(function (response)
            {
                $scope.start= response.start;
                $scope.end= response.end;
                $scope.step = response.step;

 $scope.mytime = new Date();


$scope.options = {
hstep: [1, 2, 3],
mstep: [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
};

$scope.hstep = 1;
$scope.mstep = 30;

$scope.ismeridian = false;
$scope.toggleMode = function() {
$scope.ismeridian = ! $scope.ismeridian;
};

$scope.update = function() {
var d = new Date();
d.setHours( 14 );
d.setMinutes( 0 );
$scope.mytime = d;
};

$scope.changed = function(){
$scope.maxTime = $scope.max;
$scope.minTime = $scope.min;
$scope.stepTime = $scope.step;
$scope.maxTimeStep = $scope.maxTime + $scope.stepTime;
console.log($scope.maxTimeStep);
};

$scope.clear = function() {
$scope.mytime = null;
};
 });
```

With provided that if the chosen start time of 22:00, and the range is 4 hours, timepicker after 24:00 must switch to 01:00. And after the selection, send the selected value on the backend. I tried to ui.bootstrap.timepicker, but I do not know how to set up custom values, and that after a 24 hour shift counter to the 01:00, I hope you understand, thank you

Here is [plunker][1]

```
[1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/dJmNNQlJEglxi4mDp0ex?p=preview
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] (not just a link)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox is this better?

Comment: Yes. That is much better.